# Converting JS to Mithril (using Chartkick)

Tags: javascript, chartkick, mithril.js

I'm trying to add Chartkick to an application that uses Mithril.

How would I convert the code below to be used with Mithril?

```
<h1>Line Chart</h1>
<div id="line" style="height: 300px;"></div>
<script>
  new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-1", "/stocks")
</script>
```

The Mithril page:

```
import m from 'mithril';
import _ from 'underscore';
import h from '../h';
import projectShareBox from './project-share-box';
import facebookButton from './facebook-button';
import addressTag from './address-tag';
import categoryTag from './category-tag';

const projectHighlight = {
    controller() {
        return {
            displayShareBox: h.toggleProp(false, true)
        };
    },
    view(ctrl, args) {
        const project = args.project;

        return m('#project-highlight', [
            m('.w-row.u-marginbottom-60', [
                m('.w-col.w-col-12.u-text-center', {
                    style: {
                        'min-height': '300px'
                    }
                }
            ]),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`oncreate` vnode lifecycle hook](https://mithril.js.org/lifecycle-methods.html#oncreate).

Here's an example:

```
m.mount(document.body, {
    view() {
        return m(".chart", {
            oncreate(vnode) {
                vnode.state.chart = new Chartkick.LineChart(
                    vnode.dom,
                    {
                        one : 1,
                        two : 2,
                        three : 3
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Working example of that code: https://jsbin.com/gogucuv/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks Tivac! The link doesn't seem to be working due to a "502 Bad Gateway" error, so I'll try to view it later.

Comment: tried by including both the scripts in the application template and the Minthrill, but the .chart div is blank. Do you have any suggestions on why this may be happening?

Comment: Ask in the mithril gitter room and someone should be able to help!